# ROR - ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, activesupport, public-activity

I am trying to do minor upgrade from ruby 2.3.1 to 2.3.8 and facing some issues. Everything was working fine until I run the command `rake db:create` and find the following error -

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/activity_extension.rb:10:in `<module:Admin>'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/activity_extension.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/engine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin.rb:1:in `require'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/application/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/application/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

I have also traced the error and find the following information -

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: No connection pool for PublicActivity::ORM::ActiveRecord::Activity
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:570:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.11.3/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:230:in `table_exists?'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:47:in `<class:Activity>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:22:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:19:in `<module:ORM>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:18:in `<module:PublicActivity>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record/activity.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record.rb:4:in `require_relative'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/orm/active_record.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity.rb:53:in `inherit_orm'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/models/activity.rb:4:in `<module:PublicActivity>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/public_activity-1.6.4/lib/public_activity/models/activity.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/activity_extension.rb:10:in `<module:Admin>'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/activity_extension.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.11.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin/engine.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin.rb:1:in `require'
/home/user/application/engines/admin/lib/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/user/application/config/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/user/application/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.8/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
```

I am unable to find the root cause of error. Please help!

**EDIT -**

I have tried to install the application with same version of ruby on different system and it still shows the same error. Is there any issue with the new system's configuration?

This is the database.yml file -

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: -----
  password: -----
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: -----
```

Comment: if you're upgrading, do you need to create a new database?  aren't you going to be continuing with the existing one?

Comment: @jad I have cloned an existing project in another system and trying to upgrade it there.

Comment: can you edit your question and add in a copy of your database config (hiding passwords if necessary)?

Comment: @jad Sure! you can see the database.yml file. I have added the code.

Comment: have you got postgres installed on your local machine, and can you list the databases in it using `psql -l` ?

Comment: Yes postges is working fine and I can list all the databases using ```psql -l``` command.

Answer (score 0):

adding as an answer, to include code blocks:

**my database.yml:**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: project-dev

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: project-test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: project
```

the adapter assumes localhost and port, and assumes username based on the current username (I access it without a password).

I don't know if the `pool` or `timeout` values are essential, but this configuration works for me.

Comment: okay, can you paste into your question your `Gemfile.lock`? I'm going to see if I can set up my environment with the same versions